# Change background inside ListView on context menu open and close in Android

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a ListView in which each item contains two TextViews. What I'd like is to change the background colour of the TextViews when context menu opens and then change the colours back to default colour when context menu closes.

I am able to change the colour when context menu opens but not when it closes and I've not had much success searching Google for this. I've tried using onContextMenuClosed but cannot get a reference to the selected list item.

Me code:

```
list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Actions");
        MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Delete");
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        changeCol(info.targetView);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting a global variable in the `onItemLongClickListener` event of `ListView` and then using that variable inside the `onContextMenuClosed` event.

Which worked well for me.